# 3 nested if constructs

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Sorry but I can't understand why it gives me in out `"ok"` even if the second `if` is not true!

```
val = ('zxyea')

print("val")

if ("a") or ("b") in val.lower():
    if ("c") or ("d") in val.lower(): `enter code here`
        if ("e") or ("f") in val.lower():
            print("ok")
```

This is a piece of my code:

```
if ("accendi") or ("accendere") or ("spegi") or ("spegere") or ("luce") or ("luci") in text.lower:
        
        if ("sala") or ("salone") or ("salotto") in text.lower:
            #luce_sala()
            print("sala")

        elif ("cucina") or ("mensola") in text.lower:
            #luce_cucina
            print("cucina")
            
        elif ("led") or ("diffusa") in text.lower:
            #luce_led
            print("led")
            
        elif ("tutte") or ("tutta")or ("tutto") in text.lower:
            #tutte_le_luci
            print("tutte le luci")
```

Comment: I am working on a speech recognition project and instead of recognizing a single sentence I want to make sure to recognize the words that interest me even if in random order.

Comment: You may want to make your comment into a different question. Provide the example of a sentence and words you are trying to match. Include your attempt at code. This is both the more proper way to ask (rather than as a comment to this question), and will also attract more attention (since your current question got closed). Good luck!

Comment: To check if words are contained in a sentence, split the sentence into a set (not list) of words. Use `re.split` to split on whitespace and punctuation. Then do: `if my_word in word_set: print('ok')` for each word you want to test against the sentence.

Comment: Also, you probably meant `print(val)` in the code above (no quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `("a")` evaluates to true, as well as the first item in all your `if` conditions. In each case, the second part (after the `or`) never gets evaluated at all! So it does not matter whether, for example, `("b") in val.lower()` is `True`, because it is never checked by the lazy `or`. You probably meant:

```
if 'a' in val.lower() or 'b' in val.lower():
# etc
```

**Details:**
Your original code (with minor formatting changes), explained:

```
if ("a") or ("b") in val.lower():
    if ("c") or ("d") in val.lower(): 
        if ("e") or ("f") in val.lower():
            print("ok")
```

Because of operator precedence, it is equivalent to this, which is probably not what you intended:

```
if ("a") or (("b") in val.lower()):
    if ("c") or (("d") in val.lower()): 
        if ("e") or (("f") in val.lower()):
            print("ok")
```

Now, there is nothing special about the parenthesis around the strings (most notably, the parenthesis do not make a tuple - comma does), so we can remove them, which yields this:

```
if "a" or ("b" in val.lower()):
    if "c" or ("d" in val.lower()): 
        if "e" or ("f" in val.lower()):
            print("ok")
```

Now, any non-empty string is `True`, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). And we can also evaluate the other operand to the right of `or` (for our own interest, not because the Python interpreter evaluates them). Note that `val = ('zxyea')`. The end result is this:

```
if True or False:
    if True of False: 
        if True or False:
            print("ok")
```

Or simply:

```
if True:
    if True: 
        if True:
            print("ok")
```

And this, of course, prints `ok`.

Comment: It's interesting. Any idea why the following works:

```if ("c") or ("d") in val.lower():
        
            print("ok")```

Comment: What do you mean, "works"? It will always print "ok", no matter the value of `val.lower()`, because `"c"` is truthy. `"d" in val.lower()` will never be executed.

Comment: @Mahdiar It works because it is equivalent to: `if (("c")) or (("d") in val.lower()): print("ok")`. Here, `("c")` is `True`, so it prints 'ok'.

Comment: Makes sense, still trying to figure our simple things. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Is your intention to check whether the sentence has any one of the two words? Or do you want to know why the above code always prints `ok`?

Comment: why the code always print 'ok'

Comment: @Chris Please see updated answer.